# 2d engine/library for android in C#

Tags: c#, 2d, android, physics

I'm looking for a good 2d engine or library (that supports physics) for Android. I have a restriction - language should be C#. 
It's not a requirement to use Mono Droid, but it seems that it is an only way.

What can you suggest?

Comment: I believe that native android programming is done in Java, so you'll have to use something like Mono Droid if you want to use C#.

Comment: Yep, I know about Mono Droid. But I'm looking for the ways to simplify development, so I do not need to create my own 2d engine

Comment: Sorry, I should have put an emphasis on "have" there. I got the Mono Droid from your question. I just meant you have no choice but to use something like that because Android is Java based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Velcro Physics](https://github.com/Genbox/VelcroPhysics) (formerly Farseer Physics) is probably the best 2D physics engine for .NET.

If XNA level library is enough you can try [MonoGame](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame).

If you want to go even more high level then try [Unity](http://unity3d.com).

I wouldn't be surprised if running physics via Mono on Android will turn out to be slow.
Some people have issues in iOS with the older version of Farseer. There should be improvements on this side in Velcro Physics.

I would recommend to try some very similar sample first to check if it is possible to get desired performance.

Comment: It seems that Farseer is something I was looking for. But I'm not sure is it support Android?

Comment: @Archeg Not yet officially in this release (3.3). However you should be able to use it with Mono as any other .Net assembly. The only issue is that you will probably have to fix basic types like Vector2 manually.

Comment: @Archeg check these links as well:

http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/discussions/276840
http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/discussions/277386

Answer (score 0):

There is a C# wrapper for the box2d engine:
http://code.google.com/p/box2dx/

Comment: Farseer is also based on Box2D this seems like it hasn't been updated since 2010. :(